# How can I install phppgadmin on WAMP server?

Tags: php, postgresql, wamp

I have a 64 bit WAMP server. 
I found a description, and I followed the instructions, but it doesn't worked. 
I rewritethe followed lines in php.ini:
 from this

```
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll 
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
```

to this

```
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll 
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
```

After that, I created a phppgadmin.conf named into the directory below:

C:\wamp64\alias

The content of the phppgadmin.conf file is:

```
Alias /phppgadmin "C:/wamp64/apps/phpPgAdmin-5.1/" 

<Directory "C:/wamp64/apps/phpPgAdmin-5.1/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
    Require local
</Directory>
```

And I copied the phpPgAdmin-5.1 map into the the directory below:

C:\wamp64\apps

And I ticked the php_pdo_pgsql and the php_pgsql in php extensions.

And the error messages are:

"( ! ) Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; Decorator has a deprecated constructor in C:\wamp64\apps\phpPgAdmin-5.1\libraries\decorator.inc.php on line 92
"

"( ! ) Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; FieldDecorator has a deprecated constructor in C:\wamp64\apps\phpPgAdmin-5.1\libraries\decorator.inc.php on line 103
"

"( ! ) Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; ArrayMergeDecorator has a deprecated constructor in C:\wamp64\apps\phpPgAdmin-5.1\libraries\decorator.inc.php on line 115
"

"( ! ) Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; ConcatDecorator has a deprecated constructor in C:\wamp64\apps\phpPgAdmin-5.1\libraries\decorator.inc.php on line 130
"

"( ! ) Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; CallbackDecorator has a deprecated constructor in C:\wamp64\apps\phpPgAdmin-5.1\libraries\decorator.inc.php on line 145
"

"( ! ) Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; IfEmptyDecorator has a deprecated constructor in C:\wamp64\apps\phpPgAdmin-5.1\libraries\decorator.inc.php on line 157
"

"( ! ) Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; UrlDecorator has a deprecated constructor in C:\wamp64\apps\phpPgAdmin-5.1\libraries\decorator.inc.php on line 174
"

"( ! ) Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; replaceDecorator has a deprecated constructor in C:\wamp64\apps\phpPgAdmin-5.1\libraries\decorator.inc.php on line 200
"

"Configuration error: Copy conf/config.inc.php-dist to conf/config.inc.php and edit appropriately."

Answer (score 2):

you need to upgrade phpPgAdmin to a version that works with PHP7, see this fork https://github.com/Tomicapo/phppgadmin

you als need to uncomment your php.ini lines like this

```
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
```